# triangle group representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, deformation-theory

Let $G_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}$ be a hyperbolic triangle group. Then $G$ has a following presentation.
$G=\langle a, b; a^{\alpha}, b^{\beta}, c^{\gamma}, abc\rangle, \alpha, \beta, \gamma \geq 2$.
Suppose that  $G_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}$ is a finite index subgroup of some other hyperbolic triangle group $G_{\alpha_{1},\beta_{1},\gamma_{1}}$.Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a subgroup of $SL(3,\mathbb{R})$  isomorphic to $G_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}$.
Then is it true that there exists a group $\Gamma_{1}$ in $SL(3,\mathbb{R})$ which is isomorphic to $G_{\alpha_{1},\beta_{1},\gamma_{1}}$ and contains $\Gamma$ as a finite index subgroup?
Is there any counterexample or some condition that this happens? What happens in $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: If you have the extra conditions on embedding of $\Gamma$ in $SL(3,R)$, namely, acting properly on a convex domain in $RP^2$, then the answer is yes. Otherwise, not enough is known about representations of triangle groups to $SL(3,R)$. For counter-examples: Do you really need a representation to $SL(3,R)$ to be injective? Injectivity is hard to verify, maybe a weaker form of injectivity would be enough for you. There are potential (nondiscrete of course) counter-examples in the case of $SL(2,R)$: There is no obvious kernel, but I am not sure if the representations are injective. 

Comment: For the case when $\Gamma$ acts properly on a convex domain in $RP^{2}$, is the same statement true for every such $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma_{1}$(when $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma_{1}$ are not necessarily triangle groups)? Is there a reference for the proof? Thanks.

Comment: The statement fails for non-triangle groups and their representations to $SL(2,R)$. Say, a generic closed hyperbolic surface $S$ of genus $\ge 3$, does not isometrically cover any hyperbolic orbifold (except for $S$ itself), and group embeddings as in your question, correspond to such coverings.  The statement about coverings is a simple corollary of calculation of dimensions of Teichmuller spaces of hyperbolic orbifolds. The argument for triangle groups is not in the literature and I would have to write it up. The key is that spaces of  convex-projective structures on ...  

Comment: ...orbifolds of the type $S^2(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ are all diffeomorphic to $R^2$ as long as $\alpha,\beta,\gamma>2$. 
This fact is due to Weil-Hitchin-Goldman-Choi. 
(The  dimension count here fails if one of your generators is an 
involution, so there will be counter-examples in this case.) The last ingredient is that one space of projective structures is properly embedded in the other, so they have to be the same. This is again essentially due to Hitchin-Goldman-Choi.


Comment: The counter-examples will be of the type $G_{n,n,n}< G_{2,3,2n}$, $n\ge 4$. There will be discrete embeddings of $G_{n,n,n}$ to $SL(3,R)$ which do not extend to $G_{2,3,2n}$.  Same for $G_{n,n,m}<G_{2,2m,n}$. But these are the only counter-examples in the context of groups acting properly on convex domains. 

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I would like to ask you one more question. If two convex real projective orbifolds have same fundamental groups and the fundamental group is a triangle group, then  are the two orbifolds homeomorphic?

Comment: For the above question I would like to assume that the orbifolds are two dimensional.

Comment: Yes, they are homeomorphic: Topologically these are the usual 2-dimensional orbifolds, just they come equipped with the extra structure. By the way, I was implicitly assuming that universal cover of these convex orbifolds is projectively isomorphic a convex bounded domain the the affine plane. Examples are given by closed 2-dimensional hyperbolic orbifolds (use projective model of hyperbolic plane). If one of the generators is an involution, this is the only example, while if none of the generators is an involution, then hyperbolic examples can be nontrivially deformed.  

Comment: According to Takeuchi's paper "Commensurability classes of arithmetic triangle groups" $G_{3,6,18}$ is a $4$-index subgroup of $G_{2,3,18}$.
So this is also a counter-example? 

Comment: Yes, this is also a counter-example: I was looking at the case of normal subgroups, but I guess, there are more groups that have to be excluded when you consider non-normal subgroups like in this example. Somebody probably compiled a list of embeddings of triangle groups since Takeuchi's work, that you should search for the examples where $(2,n,m)$ group contains $(p,q,r)$-group, where $p, q, r$ are all different from 2.  All these would yield counter-examples. 